# User Control in Master Page loads first

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, master-pages

I have a User Control in a Master Page that calculates quantity of products in the shopping basket and writes to page something like shopping cart(2), showing that you have 2 products.
When you add a product to basket, User Control loads first and then Add method of the page executes because of the page life cycle.

So In order to see the new added product takes effect - shopping cart(3) - i need to refresh the page..

What is the best solution in order to see this after add to cart button is pressed with no refreshing the site.

Do I need to use master page's pre_render event?

Comment: You should not use the load event to handle events. Instead you should provide custom events in your UserControl that your MasterPage will handle and processes further. Raise another custom event declared in the Master that your page then handles. This is the correct way to communicate between your UserControl in Master and the Page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a look at the [ASP.Net page life cycle](http://devio.wordpress.com/2012/01/07/asp-net-4-application-and-page-life-cycle-with-data-binding/), you'll find that the LoadComplete (for pages only) and PreRender events are called after the postback handlers.

It should be sufficient to move your shopping cart calculation into the User Control's PreRender event.

Answer (score 0):

Just take care of the actual order of event execution, and call your logic accordingly:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Normally the Master Page UC should subscribe to an event which is fired by the page whenever an item is added.

Answer (score 0):

Best way of doing is to use the custom Event in user control.

How ever if you don't want to use that, you can use a work around. Simply create a property of user control to show count and updates its value in Add method of that page.